# GCC warning: unused parameter miniz_zip

Tags: c, gcc

Вот как так происходит?

код:

```
#define MZ_ZIP_ARRAY_SET_ELEMENT_SIZE(array_ptr, element_size) (array_ptr)->m_element_size = element_size

#if defined(DEBUG) || defined(_DEBUG) || defined(NDEBUG)
/* ниже строка 294 */
static MZ_FORCEINLINE mz_uint mz_zip_array_range_check(const mz_zip_array *pArray, mz_uint index)
{
    MZ_ASSERT(index < pArray->m_size);
    return index;
}
#define MZ_ZIP_ARRAY_ELEMENT(array_ptr, element_type, index) ((element_type *)((array_ptr)->m_p))[mz_zip_array_range_check(array_ptr, index)]
#else
#define MZ_ZIP_ARRAY_ELEMENT(array_ptr, element_type, index) ((element_type *)((array_ptr)->m_p))[index]
#endif
```

ошибка:

```
miniz_zip.c: In function 'mz_zip_array_range_check':
miniz_zip.c:294:76: warning: unused parameter 'pArray' [-Wunused-parameter]
 static MZ_FORCEINLINE mz_uint mz_zip_array_range_check(const mz_zip_array *pArray, mz_uint index)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, макрос `MZ_ASSERT` в релизе (а может и в дебаге), вырождается в пустую строку. Поэтому, переменная и не используется. И компилятор абсолютно прав - ведь препроцессор отработал раньше.

Что делать? можно просто убрать этот warning, а можно явно подсказать компилятору, что не нужно тревожиться. Где то так

```
static MZ_FORCEINLINE mz_uint mz_zip_array_range_check(__attribute__((unused)) const mz_zip_array *pArray, mz_uint index)
{
    MZ_ASSERT(index < pArray->m_size);
    return index;
}
```

Comment: Точно! Пошел проверять макрос :)